# SQL Server fails to connect to database on client

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, and now when I want to open that database using SQL Server Management Studio on the client machine it fails to open.

But the database opens normally on the server.

The owner of the database is `sa` and on client I am logged in with windows authentication.

How to resolve this error??

> the server priciple smtech/prabhu is not able to access the database
>   the user is of client under the server domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making sure that the account you are trying to connect with actually has access.

Log onto the server, open up management studio, look in object explorer. There should be a Security folder icon in the treeview, Expand that and the Logins folder.

If the user you are trying to connect with isnt present you may need to add it.

Other than this instead of connecting with windows authentication maybe try connect with SQL Server Authentication as the SA user?

Answer (score 0):

Is both Client and DB sever are on SAME domain ?? If not, then I think Windows Authentication will not work for you. 
(As already suggested in above answer) create a SQL Login try with to connect DB from Client using that Login.

If both machine are on same domain and still you are not able to connect server, then few things you can check,

1. Can your client actually "see" this server over network ??
2. Most common reason is firewall. By default SQL Server communicates from port 1433 and 1434. Try to see if this [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932) link helps
3. Make sure that your SQL Server instance is configured to communicate using TCP/IP. This can be configured from SQL Server Configuration Manager.